# advanced data binding in Polymer

Tags: polymer

i have a little problem that i can not solve on my own.
I have custom element:

```
<dom-module id="station">
   <template>
     <country-iso-alpha3 id="country" selected={{country}}></country-iso-alpha3>
   </template>
```

this custom element **station** has **country** property with *CZE* default value.

if we look in **country-iso-alpha3** :

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="type" selected="{{selected}}" >
        <paper-item type="CZE">
            <span>CZE</span>
        </paper-item>
        <paper-item type="ENG">
            <span>ENG</span>
        </paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

properties of **country-iso-alpha3** are:

```
properties: {
    label: {},
    selected: {},
},
```

what i am trying to achieve is that when user tap on paper item inside paper menu, property **country** in **station** element should update. But the only thing that is updated is *selected* attribute in **station**

Is there any way how to achieve this? Maybe this is already 3 way data binding.

I know, my english is not best and this is not so easy to demonstrate so if you do not undestand i can try to explain it a little bit better

Comment: Polymer custom elements cannot have names without `-` in between. So, `station` is an invalid name

Comment: yep sorry, for easier explanation i just renamed it to station but originaly i have that char in name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `country-iso-alpha3` element, configure `selected` to propagate changes upward. This can be done by setting `notify: true`.

```
properties: {
    selected: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
    }
},
```

By default, changes are not propagated to the parent element ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#data-flow)).

Comment: thank you so much :) i have been using polymer for about 2 weeks and i had not enough time to learn it bcs of lack of time in work :) i appreciate it

Comment: you're welcome :) grasping all the details takes some time. I'm still learning, too