# Cannot pass bound value of select box to second polymer element

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I'm very new to Polymer and am having quite a time making this work. I've spent a few days scanning the docs at Google and other questions posed here on SE. My problem is similar to this one:

[advanced data binding in Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918908/advanced-data-binding-in-polymer)

But I can't seem to get my code to run even after trying to apply the answers to this question and others. I have two elements and I just want to pass the value of the {{selected}} binding from one (my-symptom):

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-symptom">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  <iron-ajax
      auto
      url="../data/topic1/symptom1/data.json"
      handle-as="json"
      last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">2</div>
      <h1>Causes</h1>
      <p>Please select a <strong>Cause</strong> that you wish to troubleshoot from the list below.</p>
    <paper-listbox attr-for-selected="data-key" selected="{{selected}}" id="causeSelect">
       <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">
             <paper-item data-key="{{item.solution}}"><a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.cause}}</a></paper-item>
      </template>
 </paper-listbox>
 </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
      is: 'my-symptom',
      properties: {
        selected:{
          type: String,
          notify: true
        }
      }
  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

to the other (my-solution):

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-symptom.html">


<dom-module id="my-solution">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
      <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">3</div>
      <h1>Solutions</h1>
      <p>Here is the <strong>Solution</strong> that corresponds to the cause you selected.</p>
      <my-symptom selected="{{selected}}"></my-symptom>
</template>

  <script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-solution'
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Within the first element, the code outputs the expected value for {{selected}}, if I set the binding to appear in that element. however, when I try to insert it into my-solution using the selected attribute, I get everything except the selected value from my-cause.

This seems like it should be really simple, but obviously there are many things I don't yet understand about Polymer. Thanks in advance for any help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting response for ajax? because you are missing `iron-ajax` import. Other then that only error in your code is unbalnaced `div` in botht the elements. I ran your code in my local with minor variation and it works fine for me

Comment: Thanks @a1626 for having a look at this. I corrected the div tags and added the iron-ajax import (strange that I was getting a response without it, though I imported it on another page in the app). I'm still not getting the expected response for `<my-symptom selected={{selected}}></my-symptom>`.  Am I mistaken in expecting it to insert only the selected value, a string loaded from the previous page's JSON in `<paper-listbox>` here in the the <my-solution> element?

Comment: How do you know you are not getting `selected`? Where are you using it? I don't see that in the snippet pasted above. I simply printed in it HTML and it was working for me

Comment: The value for `{{selected}}` doesn't appear in `<my-solution>`, but it does when I print the value in `<my-symptom>` , so I know that it has been loaded and parsed correctly by iron-ajax and passed along to attr-for-selected correctly. Am I maybe missing an observer here? From the documentation, it seemed like bindings and their values are automatically tracked by the data system.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly are you using `selected`(code if possible). Anyways in that case why have you used selected as attribute and binded it in `my-solution`

Comment: I'm using selected here to create a binding on the selected value of the paper-list element `<paper-listbox attr-for-selected="data-key" selected="{{selected}}" id="causeSelect">
       <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">
             <paper-item data-key="{{item.solution}}"><a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.cause}}</a></paper-item>
      </template>` and then I want to receive its value in the <my-solution> element, here: ` 
      <p>Here is the <strong>Solution</strong> that corresponds to the cause you selected.</p>
      <my-symptom selected="{{selected}}"></my-symptom>`

Comment: All i see is you reading value of `paper-listbox's` `selected` and then sending that same value to `my-solution`. But i don't see you using it anywhere. Your value has already reached `my-solution` but you are not doing anything with it

Comment: Okay, I guess I'm not quite understanding how this all works. Would you mind posting some code that would demonstrate how to expose the value of `select` in `my-solution`? I would very much appreciate the help since I can't seem to figure out what I"m doing wrong here. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your code except for the one's mentioned in comments(unbalanced div tag and missing iron-ajax). The only thing that i see is that you have not used/printed `selected` anywhere in your `my-solution`.
Below snippet contains your code where i've printed `selected` in `my-solution` and it's working as expected.

I've replaced iron-ajax call with hardcoded value for the sake of demo. This code will work fine even with ajax call

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite-min-js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-symptom">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- commenting for the sake of demo -->
    <!-- <iron-ajax
               auto
               url="data/data.json"
               handle-as="json"
               last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax> -->

    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">2</div>
      <h1>Causes</h1>
      <p>Please select a <strong>Cause</strong> that you wish to troubleshoot from the list below.</p>
      <!-- binding paper-listbox's selected to my-symptom's selected -->
      <paper-listbox attr-for-selected="data-key" selected="{{selected}}" id="causeSelect">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">
          <paper-item data-key="{{item.solution}}">{{item.cause}}</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-listbox>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-symptom',
      properties: {
        selected: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        },
        response: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [{
              "solution": "1",
              "url": "1",
              "cause": "1"
            }, {
              "solution": "2",
              "url": "2",
              "cause": "2"
            }, {
              "solution": "3",
              "url": "3",
              "cause": "3"
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<link rel="import" href="iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-solution">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">3</div>
      <h1>Solutions</h1>
      <p>Here is the <strong>Solution</strong> that corresponds to the cause you selected.</p>
      <!-- binding my-symptom's selected to my-solution's selected -->
      <my-symptom selected="{{selected}}"></my-symptom>
      <!-- printing my-solution's selected. You can also read this value in js using this.selected -->
      My Solution: {{selected}}
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-solution'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<my-solution></my-solution>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This works and I've marked the answer correct. I'm still struggling to get my head around the way the data binding system works in Polymer. Thanks once again, I really appreciate the help!